# Flask running javascript differently on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am working on a super mario recreation in js. I am using Flask to serve html, css, and javascript. The issue I am having is that the site often stops working when I refresh with F5. It works perfectly when I initially navigate to the site, or if i close the tab and go there again. Shift + F5 also works. I have no idea what could be causing this issue, altough i suspect that it may have something to do with the cache.

Here is the html I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="15">
    <!-- The actual resolution of the NES is 256x240.
         Ideally, we draw in this size and scale appropriately.-->
    <title>Super Mario Bros</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/game.css">
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: rgb(32,35,36)">
    <div class="controls">
      <p id = "CurrentLevelInfo"></p>
      <p> Press CTRL + F5 if you haven't played in a while. This ensures that you get updates. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="controls" style="align-content: center; text-align: center;">
      <h2> Controls (<a onclick="viewKeyConfig()" style="color: blue; cursor: pointer"> REBIND </a>)</h2>
      <p class="controls" id="LeftKeyLabel"> </p> <p class="controls" id="RightKeyLabel"> </p>
      <p class="controls" id="JumpKeyLabel"> </p>  <p class="controls" id="RunKeyLabel" > </p>
    </div>
    <div id="EndDiv" class="fadeMe" style="text-align: center">
      <h1> Thank you for participating! </h1>
      <p> You have completed all the levels included within this study. You can now safely exit the website. If you return, you will not be able to play any more levels, this is to avoid duplicate data. </p>
    </div>
    <div id="BackgroundFormDiv" class="fadeMe">
      <h1 class="likert-header">Hello! Before you start, we would like some background information. Please note that no identifying data will be stored.</h1>
      <form id="BackgroundForm" action="">
        <label for="Age" class="statement"> Age </label>
        <input type="number" id="Age" name="Age" style="margin-left: 9%; margin-top: 1%; font-size: 20px">
        <label for="Gender" class="statement"> Gender </label>
        <ul id="Gender" class='likert'>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Woman">
            <label>Woman</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Man">
            <label>Man</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Other">
            <label>Other</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <label for="GamingExperience" class="statement"> Amount of experience playing games </label>
        <ul id="GamingExperience" class='likert'>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="GamingExperience" value="None">
            <label>None</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="GamingExperience" value="Some">
            <label>Some</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="GamingExperience" value="Moderate">
            <label>Moderate</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="GamingExperience" value="Much">
            <label>Much</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="GamingExperience" value="Very much">
            <label>Very much</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="QualityFormDiv" class="fadeMe">
      <h1 class="likert-header">Good job! Please rate the level according to the criteria below.</h1>
      <form id="QualityForm" action="">
        <label for="Enjoyment" class="statement"> Enjoyment </label>
        <ul id="Enjoyment" class='likert'>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Enjoyment" value="Very Low">
            <label>Very Low</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Enjoyment" value="Low">
            <label>Low</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Enjoyment" value="Moderate">
            <label>Moderate</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Enjoyment" value="High">
            <label>High</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Enjoyment" value="Very High">
            <label>Very High</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <label for="Aesthetics" class="statement"> Aesthetics </label>
        <ul id="Aesthetics" class='likert'>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Aesthetics" value="Very Low">
            <label>Very Low</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Aesthetics" value="Low">
            <label>Low</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Aesthetics" value="Moderate">
            <label>Moderate</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Aesthetics" value="High">
            <label>High</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Aesthetics" value="Very High">
            <label>Very High</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <label for="Difficulty" class="statement"> Difficulty </label>
        <ul id="Difficulty" class='likert'>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Difficulty" value="Very Low">
            <label>Very Low</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Difficulty" value="Low">
            <label>Low</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Difficulty" value="Moderate">
            <label>Moderate</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Difficulty" value="High">
            <label>High</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="Difficulty" value="Very High">
            <label>Very High</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="introDiv" id="introDiv">
      <div style="width: 75%; margin: auto;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center"> Hello, and thank you very much for participating in this study </h1>
        <h2>  The following is a brief introduction to what you will be doing in this study. You will play through twenty super mario levels. To complete a Super Mario level, simply move from left to right
          until you touch the flagpole (not the rectangle it is standing on, jump into it). Make sure to avoid the Goombas (the mushroom looking guys).
          You can jump into the yellow blocks with question marks on them to get rewards. You can either get a coin, which don't really help you, or you can get a mushroom. Touch the mushroom to grow larger.
          When you are in this enlarged state you can touch a goomba without failing the level. Instead you will shrink and become invulnerable for a short time (indicated by Mario blinking).
          Make sure to run (hold shift) when you can. This will cause you to jump further and faster (You also bounce further when you jump on goombas if you are running).
          After the completion of each level you will be prompted to rate the level in three aspects: difficulty, enjoyment, and aesthetics.
          Please take a moment to consider your ratings before leaving them. The data you create through your ratings
          will be used to investigate the effectiveness of a level generator built using Artificial Intelligence, the levels you are playing through are generated by that generator. </h2>

          <h2>
            Please note that this site uses cookies to save your position and connect your level ratings to the background information you will be aksed to provide shortly. See our
            <a href="../static/privacy-policy_new.html" target="_blank" style="color: blue; cursor: pointer"> privacy policy </a>.
          </h2>
        <h2>
          That's all you need to know, click <a onclick="document.getElementById('introDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden'" style="color: blue; cursor: pointer"> here </a> to start!
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "controlConfigDiv" id = "controlConfigDiv">
      <div style="width: 75%; height: 75%; margin: auto">
        <ul style="margin: auto;">
          <li>
            <label> Left </label> <button class="buttons" onclick="startKeyRebind('Left')" id="LeftKeyButton"> </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label> Right </label> <button class="buttons" onclick="startKeyRebind('Right')" id="RightKeyButton"> </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label> Jump </label> <button class="buttons" onclick="startKeyRebind('Jump')" id="JumpKeyButton"> </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label> Run </label> <button class="buttons" onclick="startKeyRebind('Run')" id="RunKeyButton"> </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button class="buttons" onclick="hideKeyConfig()"> Close </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fadeMe">
      <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; margin: auto; text-align: center;">
        <h1> Press desired key to rebind </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/levels/levelsJson.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/util.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/input.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/resources.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/sprite.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/entity.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/pipe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/mushroom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/fireflower.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/star.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/fireball.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/coin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/bcoin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/goomba.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/koopa.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/floor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/block.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/rubble.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/prop.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/player.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/flag.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/levels/level.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/levels/levelparser.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/game.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the Flask code:

```
import datetime
import random
from flaskext.autoversion import Autoversion

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
# app.autoversion = False
# Autoversion(app)

buildid = random.randint(0, 1000000)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    # For the sake of example, use static information to inflate the template.
    # This will be replaced with real information in later steps.

    return render_template("index_new.html")


#192.168.1.135

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
    # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This
    # can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to app.yaml.
    # Flask's development server will automatically serve static files in
    # the "static" directory. See:
    # http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files. Once deployed,
    # App Engine itself will serve those files as configured in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=14545, debug=True)
```

And finally, an image of the project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Comment: What do you mean by “the site often stops working?” Is the index_new.html template not rendered? Do you get a 500 response?

Comment: You seem to have some unused stuff in your code. Besides of that there is nothing in the flask code that explains your observations.

Comment: The site renders, but sometimes the game itself does not, it's almost like rhe javascript ran into sn error. Other times, the game renders, but rhe controls don't work. I don't think it's an error, because it only happens on refresh. But maybe the js is somehow loaded differently.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was quite specific to my JS code.